# Strange function call in constructor c++

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm coding an enigma machine, and having issues making a constructor for my machine class. It appears a constructor for a plugboard is being called despite the fact a plugboard must be provided in the arguments to the constructor. Here is the error

```
Machine.cpp: In constructor ‘Machine::Machine(std::list<Rotor>, Plugboard)’:
Machine.cpp:6:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘Plugboard::Plugboard()’
 Machine::Machine(list<Rotor> rots, Plugboard pb) {
```

Machine.cpp:

```
#include "Machine.h"

using namespace std;


Machine::Machine(list<Rotor> rots, Plugboard pb) {

  plugboard = pb;
  rotors = rots;

}

//give c's alphabet index
int Machine::getPosition(char c) {
  if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
    return c - 'A';
  }
  else  {
    cout <<  "not an accepted character";
    return -1;
  }
}

//give letter at index i in alphabet
char Machine::atPosition(int i) {
  assert(i>=0 && i<=25);
  return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[i];
}

char Machine::encode(char c) {
  assert(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
  //plugboard
  c = plugboard.getMatch(c);
  //forward pass through rotors
  c = rotors[0].process(c);
  //reflector
  c = Reflector::reflect(c);
  //backwards pass through rotors
  c = rotors[0].processInverse(c);
  return c;

}
```

Machine.h:

```
#ifndef MACHINE_H
#define MACHINE_H

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <list>
#include "Reflector.h"
#include "Rotor.h"
#include "Plugboard.h"

class Machine{

  public:

    Machine(std::list<Rotor> rots, Plugboard pb);   
    static int getPosition(char c);
    static char atPosition(int i);
    char encode(char c);

  private:

    std::list<Rotor> rotors;
    Plugboard plugboard;

};

#endif
```

Comment: You copy the list of rotors twice. Why?

Comment: Im not sure what youre referring to

Comment: Your constructor passes the list by value, which results in a copy. It then copies the copy into the member variable. Why not pass by const reference and prevent a copy?

Answer (score 5):

That's because in your constructor, you're first default-constructing `plugboard`, and THEN copy-assigning it. Just construct it in an initializer list. And take the arguments by `const &`!

```
Machine(const std::list<Rotor>& rots, const Plugboard& pb)
: rotors(rots)
, plugboard(pb)
{ }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Id seen this initializer list syntax before but assumed it was equivalent to the java style assignmnent I used. Could you explain the use of const &?

Comment: @AdrianRothan To avoid copies. If you pass in your list by-value, it'll get copied twice - once into the constructor and then once more into `rotors`. This way, you only get one copy.